# How do I run two different conky sessions at the same time?

Tags: unity, conky

I want to run **Conky lua** ([link to conky lua on Gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Conky+lua?content=139024)) and **Conky: Metro Clock** ([link to conky: metro clock on devianart.com](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Metro-Clock-245432929)) at the same time. I want to have them both on the start up applications. I know how to install them individualy, but I am having a rough time finding out how to get them simultaneously. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, unity desktop environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conky without parameters looks for a file named ".conkyrc" in your home folder. To use another config file you have to use the "-c" or "--config" parameter. This way you can start conky twice or how many times you want to, with each conky session using another config-file.

The included .sh-file in the archive on deviantart starts conky without parameters, so ".conkyrc" in your home-folder will be used. => The first session

If you put the "conkyrc"-file from the archive on Gnome-look in your home-folder, you can use the command "conky -c ~/conkyrc". => The second session.

Both instances of Conky should be running, independently from each other, each with its own config-file.

Comment: Where do I find the .sh file or its equivalent? Kubuntu 19.10. Maybe it works differently now?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a second conky command for running a second instance of conky in the .sh file provided in the package.
That is just add another conky -c ~/.conkyrc under the command wrritten in .sh file